# R: Find slope for each subset of a data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, subset, plyr

I have a data like:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=sample(1:10, 100, rep=T),
                  Date=seq(as.Date("1982/01/01"), by="16 days", length.out = 100),
                  Value1=runif(100))
```

I need to subset the data by Year and ID and fit a line to data from Jan-Jun and Jul-Dec and write out the 2 slope coefficients, I need to do that for all the combinations of Year and ID.

Is there a way to do that other than a loop? The actual data has 21788928 rows and the loop is taking too long.

Comment: It sounds like you have working code that is taking too long for this problem. Please include the working code in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be faster, but I'm not sure if it will be fast enough for your needs. Let me know:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Function to return the coefficients of the regression as a data frame
coef.fcn = function(df) {
  coeffs = coef(lm(Value1 ~ Date, data=df))
  return(data.frame(Intercept=coeffs[1], Value1=coeffs[2]))
}

lm_coefs = dat %>% 
  mutate(my.cat = ifelse(month(Date) %in% 1:6, 
                         paste("Jan-Jun", year(Date)), paste("Jul-Dec", year(Date)))) %>%
  group_by(ID, my.cat) %>%
  do(coef.fcn(.))
```

Here's a portion of the result with your sample data:

```
lm.coefs

   ID       my.cat    Intercept        Value1
1   1 Jan-Jun 1983   0.62824396            NA
2   1 Jan-Jun 1985   0.71865235            NA
3   1 Jul-Dec 1985  20.20901291 -0.0033972977
4   2 Jan-Jun 1983 -37.54324401  0.0078885381
...
45  8 Jan-Jun 1982 -30.39203349  0.0068229828
46  8 Jan-Jun 1984 -27.62517465  0.0054096259
47  8 Jan-Jun 1985  27.70049296 -0.0048539844
48  8 Jul-Dec 1982  12.90814643 -0.0025997511
49  8 Jul-Dec 1984 -16.84585961  0.0032229997
...
57 10 Jan-Jun 1982   0.63533344            NA
58 10 Jan-Jun 1983   0.35107513            NA
59 10 Jan-Jun 1984   0.59588750            NA
60 10 Jul-Dec 1982   0.05156481            NA
61 10 Jul-Dec 1983   0.54658810            NA
```